# PyQt / Qt, tableview with custom delegate to use ellipsis for text overflowing cell

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview

Without custom delegate everything works fine:

[image]

But my tableview shows search results and part of the text needs to be bold to indicate where it matches the searched query.

Once I use the delegate to get html tags working, the text that overflows cells is not cliped and replaced with ellipsis:

[image]

Heres my delegate:

```
class HTMLDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.doc = QTextDocument(self)

def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    painter.save()

    options = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
    self.initStyleOption(options, index)

    self.doc.setHtml(options.text)
    options.text = ""

    style = QApplication.style() if options.widget is None \
        else options.widget.style()
    style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)

    ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

    if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
        ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, option.palette.color(
                             QPalette.Active, QPalette.HighlightedText))

    textRect = style.subElementRect(QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, options)
    #textRect.adjust(0, 0, 0, 0)
    painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
    self.doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)

    painter.restore()

def sizeHint(self, option, index):
    return QSize(self.doc.idealWidth(), self.doc.size().height())
```

also if I would add line

```
self.doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
```

it would cut the text to the other line(I increased row height to show it):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
```

I thoughtI had it in my delegate, its in all other answers around here, well it does the clipping correctly, though no fancy ellipsis, but thats ok I guess.
I assumed previously that theres just some value that I have to enable to get clipping ellipsis, but I am starting to see that it could be considerably more complicated than that, that I might actually need to edit the text itself depending on area rectangle -  vs text width taken and adjust on every column resize or some stuff

oh, how I wish they would just make option to enable html rich text with the default delegate