# PyQt5 - QTableView + QAbstractTableModel - html format cell/column text

Tags: python, dataframe, pyqt, pyqt5, qabstracttablemodel

Is there a way, perhaps using QStyledItemDelegate (like here [PyQt / Qt, tableview with custom delegate to use ellipsis for text overflowing cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893565/pyqt-qt-tableview-with-custom-delegate-to-use-ellipsis-for-text-overflowing-c) or here [QStyledItemDelegate truncates text horizontally and doesn't add a horizontal scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600849/qstyleditemdelegate-truncates-text-horizontally-and-doesnt-add-a-horizontal-scr)), to display a QtWidgets.QTableView cell (or entire column's) text as HTML?

While changing foreground color or background color with Roles is useful, I would like to be able to have a string where most of the words are regular typeface but one or two specific words are shown in bold.

I am hoping I can, perhaps with a delegate, read in HTML that has been loaded into a QAbstractTableModel as a string, and render it as HTML.

I am open to any implementation though.  I've had a hard time finding examples/concepts that are applicable to converting a table cell or column to display as HTML.